# Django queryset custom properties

Tags: django, model, properties

I have user profile like

> class UserProfile(models.Model):
>
> ```
>     completed_tasks = models.ManyToManyField(Tasks)
> ```

then task model

> class Tasks(models.Model):
>
> ```
>     <...fields...>
> ```

Then I want to filter some task and have a queryset property "completed" that marks if task objects is in user completed_tasks.

## Example

> t = Tasks.objects.filter(...).order_by(...)
>
> t[0].completed # False
>
> t[1].completed # True

Any ideas how can I do that?

Comment: What is wrong with just having a `models.BooleanField` on the `Tasks` model called `completed`?

Comment: I have many users and many tasks. Every user can complete every task once.

Comment: Try using the `ManyToManyField` with an [intermediate/through table](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships). This allows you to associate extra data with each unique pair `(user, task)`

Answer (score 0):

Tricky question: in your model task completion depends on user having it in his collection, which makes the logic ambiguous. Is the task completed if any user completed it? Maybe all users need to complete it? Or maybe answer depends on user asking? Try making your models more defined.

Comment: Every user can complete the task once. If one user completes it, that doesn't mean that task is completed.

Comment: Assume there are n tasks in a database. Every task done gives the user a certain amount of points. When user completes a task, he can't submit the answer for it again, therefore I need to track what tasks which user has already done independently from each other.

Comment: Take a look at sye comment. Through looks like something you need: basically promote your join table to a proper model.